# Javascript | Mostrar javascript cuando checkbox esté activado

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Cómo hacer que al activar checkbox se vea el elemento javascript y cuando se deschekee que se deje de ver. No funciona tal cual tengo.

**Elemento a visualizar o no visualizar según checkbox:**

```
map.addLayer(radioSaneamiento);
```

**RadioSaneamiento es una linea discontinua dinámica en el mapa tipo leaflet:**

```
    {% for station in stations0 %}
var var1="{{ station.latitud }}";
var var2="{{ station.longitud }}";
var var3="{{ station.punto_comunicacion.latitud }}";
var var4="{{ station.punto_comunicacion.longitud }}";
if(var4){
  latlngs = [];
    latlngs.push(new L.LatLng(var1,var2));
    latlngs.push(new L.LatLng(var3,var4));
        var radioSaneamiento = L.polyline(latlngs, { //Javascript
            color: "#fe8d22",
            opacity: "0.4",
            dashArray: "10,30",
            dashSpeed: -30
          }
   document.getElementById('radioSaneamiento').addEventListener('click', function() {
  radioSaneamiento[this.checked ? 'addTo' : 'removeFrom'](map)
});

  map.fitBounds(L.latLngBounds(latlngs));
  map.addLayer(radioSaneamiento);
}
{% endfor %}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Botón:**

```
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label text-white" for="defaultCheck1">
      Activar
    </label>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
function check() {
  document.getElementById("defaultCheck1").checked = true;
       map.addLayer(radioSaneamiento);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Considero deberías agregar que es: `map.addLayer(radioSaneamiento);`

Comment: Es una linea dinámica en un mapa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Por el momento](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline) para que:

- "*SI se vea*" tenes que agregarlo al mapa (`polyline.addTo()`)
- "*NO se vea*" tenes que sacarlo del mapa (`polyline.removeFrom()`)

Ambos métodos son heredados de `Layer`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([45.51, -122.68], 13);
var arregloRadios = []; // arreglo donde guardamos TODOS los polyline

//
var latlngs = [
    [45.51, -122.68],
    [37.77, -122.43],
    [34.04, -118.2]
];
var radioSaneamiento = L.polyline(latlngs, {
  color: "#fe8d22",
  opacity: "0.4",
  dashArray: "10,30",
  dashSpeed: -30
});
arregloRadios.push(radioSaneamiento); // Agregamos el polyline al arreglo

//
document.getElementById('defaultCheck1').addEventListener('click', function() {
   // Recorremos el arreglo para mostrar/ocultar los polyline
   arregloRadios.forEach(e => e[this.checked ? 'addTo' : 'removeFrom'](map))
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id='map'></div>


<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
<label class="form-check-label text-white" for="defaultCheck1">
  Activar
</label>
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos. Ocurre que funciona perfecto pero únicamente con la última linea. Al colocarse las lineas (muchas) mediante un for cada vez con coordenadas diferentes. (He añadido al código para que se vea). Por algún motivo sólo le aplica a la última linea. ¿Cómo se podria aplicar a todas las lineas del mismo tipo o del mismo for?

Comment: Perdona Marcos, en un principio no añadí todo el código, pensando que lo que se le aplicaba a una linea se le aplicaría a todas. (Por simplicar). Al no funcionar más que en la última, he pensado que el código que había puesto era insuficiente y lo he completado. Disculpa.

Comment: @julian, he actualizado mi respuesta. Espero se entiendas y puedas aplicarlo a tu problema. Cualquier duda, avisame.

Comment: Gracias Marcos. Cuando consiga meter en array, probaré y si surge algo te comento. Muy amable.